# mysysgit & copssh on windows server remote clone / push not working

Tags: git, repository

I have setup a server with mysysgit & copssh on windows, but each time I try to perform a command to the remote server it just seems to hang on the console prompt.

When I for example try:
git clone ssh://user@server:portno/repo1

It gives back:
Cloning into repo1...

user@server ~
$

And stays on that, until I press ctrl+C to abort it.

When I login with putty to the same server, I am able to run the git command without any problems. Is there any way to enable the trace information for git? So I can see what goes wrong?, or does anyone know what this might be?

I have Git-1.7.3.1-preview20101002.exe & ICW_COPSSHCP_2.0.3_installer.zip installed.

Thanks in advance,

Erik

Comment: So it prints out the shell prompt from the server when you try to clone?

Comment: Yes, when I change the copssh to windows console prompt I see the first part of the dos console. I don't have that much linux knowledge, but it looks like the shell prompt of the server

Answer (score -1):

I've just tried installing CopSSH in a VM (I have never used it before) and it seems that if you leave it set to `Linux shell` then it forces Linux shell access only.  i.e. if you try to do `ssh user@host ls` it logs you in and leaves you at a shell prompt, when what it should do is run `ls`, display the output and then log you out again.

All the other options also do not work for one reason or another, but the `Linux shell and Sftp` works (at least for the `ssh user@host ls` test, but it should work for other things like `git clone` too.

EDIT: OK, I've tried it with git now.  I had to specify the `--upload-pack` option to `git clone` and I had to specify the path to the repository as `'C:\Documents and Settings\user\test'`.  If I tried forward slashes or `/c/Documents and Settings...` or `/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings...` or `/c/Documents\ and\ Settings...`, etc., I got an error saying:

```
fatal: '/c/Documents\ and\ Settings/user/test' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So this works for me:

```
$ git clone --upload-pack="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Git/libexec/git-core/git-upload-pack.exe" user@169.254.99.3:'c:\Documents and Settings\user\test' test
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/test/.git/
user@169.254.99.3's password: 
remote: Counting objects: 6, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (6/6), done.
```

This is with `Linux shell and Sftp` specified as the shell in CopSSH's control panel.  I also have `sftp` enabled (in the `SFTP` tab), but I doubt that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that, but that works correct in the git bash, just like it does in putty, but the git just hangs, that's what I don't understand :-)

Comment: When you say "git just hangs", do you mean you get the `user@server ~ $` prompt still?  That does not happen for me with the `Linux shell and Sftp` option.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: So my answer is still no help?